# Paging using Linq

Tags: linq

I need to apply paging logic to this Query. How can i do that?

My query is as follows,

```
myresultset = from req in myreqTable
              join streq in myStreqTable on req.ID.ToString() equals new SPFieldLookupValue( Convert.ToString( streq[FormID] ) ).LookupValue
              where (filter(req) && filter1(streq))
              join plnts in plantDetails on Convert.ToString( streq[RequestID) equals Convert.ToString(plnts[RequestID]) into mySet
              from s in mySet.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new Mytable() {
                  FormID = Convert.ToString(streq[FormID]),
                  RequestID = Convert.ToString(streq[RequestID])
              };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
recordsForCurrentPage = myresultset.Skip( recordsPerPage * pageNumber ).Take( recordsPerPage )
```

This is assuming that your page number starts with 0. Otherwise subtract 1 from `pageNumber`.

Comment: hi i have added it jst after myset. Skip( pageSize * pageIndex ).Take( pageSize ); bt still it returns all records ...

Comment: You will need to use the return value, i.e. `recordsForThisPage = myresultset.Skip(...).Take(...)`

Comment: I have 2000 records, i have added like this myresults = myresults.Skip(1 * 10).Take(10); . but it returns only one record ??..

Comment: hi chris any update ?

Answer (score 3):

Add `.Skip( pageSize * pageIndex ).Take( pageSize );` to the end of your query. Note that `pageIndex` is zero-based (so the first page is `0`, the second page is `1` and so on).

However your Linq doesn't look valid to me, and has some syntax errors. Are you sure this is your code as it is in your editor?

Comment: hi i have added it jst after myset.Skip( pageSize * pageIndex ).Take( pageSize )

Answer (score 0):

Use `Take` and `Skip` methods:

```
myresults = myresults.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

I assumed page numeration starts from `1`.